# LINQ to Entities question about orderby and null collections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am currently developing a forum. I am new to LINQ and EF. In my forum I have a display that shows a list of topics with the most recent topics first.

The problem is that "most recent" is relative to the topic's replies. So I don't want to order the list by the topic's posted date, rather I want to order the list by the topic's last reply's posted date. So that topics with newer replies pop back to the top of the list. This is rather simple if I knew that every topic had at least one reply; I would just do this:

```
var topicsQuery = from x in board.Topics
                  orderby x.Replies.Last().PostedDate descending
                  select x;
```

However, in many cases the topic has no replies. In which case I would like to use the topic's posted date instead. Is there a way within my linq query to order by `x.PostedDate` in the event that the topic has no replies? I'm getting confused by this.

With the above query, it breaks on topics with no replies because of the `x.Replies.Last()` which assumes there are replies. `LastOrDefault()` doesn't work because I need to access the PostedDate property which also assumes a reply exists.

Comment: I could probably do it by just getting all replies, looping through them and using if statements to determine if there are replies and building a new list that way. But if there is a way to do it within the query and not looping through them every time, that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var topicsQuery = from x in board.Topics
                  let lastActivityDate = x.Replies.Any() 
                         ? x.Replies.Last().PostedDate 
                         : x.PostedDate
                  orderby lastActivityDate descending
                  select x;
```

**Edit:**

To answer your comment, there is no 'let' for linq expression syntax *explicitly*. But, you can achieve the same as follows (using an intermediate select expression):

```
var topicsQuery = board.Topics.Select(x => new { 
                                                  Topic = x, 
                                                  LastActivityDate = x.Replies.Any() 
                                                      ? x.Replies.Last().PostedDate 
                                                      : x.PostedDate
                                    })
                             .OrderByDescending(p => p.LastActivityDate)
                             .Select(r => r.Topic)
```

**Edit2:**

This can be simplified further as Nicholas was suggesting, we can remove the intermediate select statement as well. Note, this wouldn't have been possible if not for differed execution.

```
var topicsQuery = board.Topics
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Replies.Any() 
                                      ? x.Replies.Last().PostedDate 
                                      : x.PostedDate);
```

Comment: I love you. you saved me a bunch of time. I was not aware of .Any() and 'let' thank you +1 and accept when the time is up and lets me.

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example of how you would use the let keyword in chain linq? Like within `.OrderBy(x => x.PostedDate)`

Comment: @Chevex: Edited the answer to provide an example.

Comment: There's in fact no need for the let clause, the ternary operator is an expression and can be passed to the orderby LINQ clause as well as the body of the OrderByDescending method lambda.

Comment: @Nicolas: I used them to show the usage (select and let), allowing more explicit readability in code for people who are not used to these.

Comment: Thank you. That latter example makes my head spin but I'm sure I'll get it. For now I'll stick to formatting my queries using the keyword expressions when I need to use `let`.

Comment: @Chevex: Simplified the query and made it terse.

Comment: Much simpler. Thank you again.

Comment: Okay, now I'm running into an issue with a query that runs on an ajax call and tries to look for updated topics and auto-update the page. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637955/linq-to-entities-query-generating-odd-error

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding a new field to your Topics data?  Something like LastActivityDate.  Set it to the topics PostedDate initially then update every time a reply is added.

I'm not a SQL Server expert but if you try to do what you're asking with a query you'll probably end up with a query that will ignore your indexes and perform a full table scan.

Comment: That's actually the way I used to do it in an old site I did with inline sql queries. I just felt like it was redundant and thanks to the above answer I can replace it.

Comment: This would also mean that when a reply was made it would update this new reply field with the reply time and the topic would come to the top of the list. But what if the user then deletes that reply? There wouldn't really be an easy way to revert back to the previous reply time. I would have to read the last reply just like I'm doing now. Far better to leave reply time dynamic based on last post IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

A typical forum has many reads and few writes, especially in this particular case. Therefore I would choose to cache the LastPostDate in an extra field. It gives some redundancy and a little bit more programming to keep the value up to date, but I think in most cases it's the best way to go.

Comment: True but it is an additional write with each reply. Also, with LINQ and lazy loading I believe grabbing the last reply date is more efficient. Same number of reads, one less write.