# LINQ to Entities query generating odd error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a forum and I'm pulling up a list of recently active topics. I'm ordering the topics either by the last reply date, or in the case of a topic having no replies, then the topic's posted date. The following query works fine:

```
        var topicsQuery = from x in board.Topics
                          let lastActivityDate = x.Replies.Any()
                                 ? x.Replies.OrderBy(y => y.PostedDate).Last().PostedDate
                                 : x.PostedDate
                          orderby lastActivityDate descending
                          select x;
```

That query works great. Every time the page loads the topics are ordered correctly. However, now I have an ajax call that looks for updated activity and runs a similar query:

```
        topics = (from x in DBContext.Topics
                  let lastActivityDate = (x.Replies.Any()
                         ? x.Replies.OrderBy(y => y.PostedDate).Last().PostedDate
                         : x.PostedDate)
                  where x.BoardID == boardID
                  where lastActivityDate > lastTopic.PostedDate
                  orderby lastActivityDate
                  select x).ToList<Topic>();
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this LINQ query? It's generating the following error:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyProject.Models.Reply Last[Reply] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyProject.Models.Reply])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because the entities are not yet loaded and Last() will be called on sql not on the generic list. So first you need to load them up before asking for Last(). The first example might have worked because the **board** already had a loaded generic list.

Try the following:

```
topics = (from x in DBContext.Topics.AsEnumerable<Topic>()
                  let lastActivityDate = (x.Replies.Any()
                         ? x.Replies.OrderBy(y => y.PostedDate).Last().PostedDate
                         : x.PostedDate)
                  where x.BoardID == boardID
                  where lastActivityDate > lastTopic.PostedDate
                  orderby lastActivityDate
                  select x).ToList<Topic>();
```

Refer to: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Comment: I can't see any difference with OP's version, could you highlight the difference?

Comment: @Jani: Updated the answer with more context.

Comment: @Mahesh that could hurts dude, you loaded all the topics in memory, it's a very expensive solution for DBMS and also Application Server, that couldn't be a good idea

Comment: @Jani: Agreed, trying to show why its not working, rather than giving an optimal way.

Comment: But I don't think that we have a better performance now, the same sql that fetch all the post would run, just the query has deffered execution and in previous code sample we had eager execution.

Comment: Try replacing the `Last` by `Take` , maybe it will be executed without err

Comment: @Jani: on performance agreed in this situation it won't be better since the result set contains the same number of records. I am no expert in EF, but if EF has a concept of batching similar to NHibernate, then AsEnumerable() would probably be better if we are filtering out some data. If there is no batching, then AsEnumerable would hurt if it goes to db for each call, in which case .ToList would be better.

Comment: I ended up scrapping this code and using an ajax call that just updates the whole page on each update anyway. Prevents a few issues like the page containing many more replies than the page would normally allow. The ajax call just passes in the topic ID and the current page number. It then receives all topics for that page and updates the display. It's much more fluid because deleted and edited replies get updated also. However, I am accepting this because it would have been helpful had I not scrapped it. It is more data transferred on every update, but I don't think it's a big deal.